# Surfaces and Rasters in DWG format

Tags: raster, dem, dwg

I have been asked to export a DEM into DWG format, is this possible? The only thing I can think of is to create a regular grid of points and to export this.

Also I have been asked to save geotiff raster images to DWG is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] which mentions that there should be only one question asked per question, and yours has two.  Also, please use the [edit] button beneath your question to improve it with the GIS software that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import a DEM (for example from an ESRI ARCII GRID or GeoTiff) into AutoCAD Civil to create a grid surface there. In base AutoCAD there is no DEM entity, but you can create 3D surface (Mesh), but this way you lost the functionality of a DEM, it'll be useful only for visualization.AFAIK there is no ready tool to import DEM into AutoCAD as a 3D Mesh. Global Mapper can export a DEM into AutoCAD DXF as 3D Mesh.

If your GeoTiff is a satellite image/orthophoto you can insert it into AutoCAD Map (and also AutoCAD Civil). If your GeoTiff is a DEM then you can convert it into 3D Mesh, but AFAIK there is no ready tool to do it.